# How do I call a callable gen2 Firebase Cloud Function in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call my Firebase gen2 function from my Flutter app, however my cloud function can't read the data sent to it nor pass it forward.

**Here's my Flutter function:**

```html
  Future<bool> _test() async {
    final httpCallable = FirebaseFunctions.instance
        .httpsCallableFromUrl(cloudFunctionsVerifyPurchase); // a valid url

    final data = <String, dynamic>{
      'dataKey1': 'dataValue1',
      'dataKey2': 'dataValue2',
    };

    final res = await httpCallable.call(data);
    print(res.data);
    return false;
  }
```

**Here's my cloud function:**

```html
exports.test = onCall(async(data,context) => {
    // Access the data sent from the Flutter app
    const dataValue1 = data.dataKey1; // null
    const dataValue2 = data.dataKey2; // null
    
    // when I console.log(data) I get a massive object, and not the object I sent. I tried doing data.body but that also returns null
    
    return {
      message: dataValue1,
      result: dataValue2,
    };
});
```

My Cloud Function Logs (You can see that 'dataKey1' & 'dataKey2' exist!):

[image]

**Flutter Function Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the `onCall()` method has changed with Cloud Functions 2nd gen: You now need to pass a unique `request` parameter which "contains `data` passed from the client app as well as additional context like authentication state" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).

So you need to adapt your code as follows:

```
exports.test = onCall(async(request) => {
    // Access the data sent from the Flutter app
    const dataValue1 = resquest.data.dataKey1; // null
    const dataValue2 = request.data.dataKey2; // null
    //...
```

Comment: Perfect! This also solved my other problem of accessing user authentication data!